# Iterating over an array of objects in Javascript - why can't I obtain current object inside for increment block?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, loops, for-loop

Let's say I have an array

```
var array = [
    {name: "woo"},
    {name: "yay"},
    {name: "hoopla"}
]
```

Why does this work

```
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    var item=array[i];
    alert(item.name) // woo, yay, hoopla
}
```

But this doesn't?

```
var item;
for (var i=0; i<array.length; item=array[i++]) {
    alert(item.name) // undefined
}
```

### Here's a jsPerf test case comparing the speed of different answers: http://jsperf.com/different-ways-to-iterate-over-an-array-of-objects/2

Answer (score 3):

In the first iteration of the loop, `item=array[i++]` has not been executed yet, so `item` still has its initial value. The third part of a `for` statement is executed in between iterations, but not when the loops starts.

Comment: Ah, exactly. This seems to work: `var item = array[0];
for (var i=1; i<array.length; item=array[i++]) {
    alert(item.name)
}`

Comment: The original method (with the assignment of `item` inside the loop) is more idiomatic and will be easier for others to read. Your version forces people to piece together how state is carried forward between iterations.

Answer (score 1):

It because the first time through the loop, the variable `item` doesn't get assigned

A `for` statement has 3 parts, the counter (var i= 0;), the limit (i<array.length;) and the incrementor(i++;)

Think of those bits as 3 different lines of code. However instead of the three lines being executed in sequence, this is what the sequence looks like

1. The 'counter' is executed and sets the variable

   The 'limit' is checked and if the boolean is `true` the code in the braces is executed

   After the code in the braces is executed, the 'incrementor' is executed

   cycle repeats from the second step till the limit returns `false`

The last bit the incrementor doesn't get executed until AFTER the code in the braces of the `for` loop has been executed, so essentially, at that point in time, item had not been assigned.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
var item;
for (var i=0; item=array[i], i<array.length; i++) {
    alert(item.name) // undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in the first iteration `item` is not defined yet, it will work if you change your code to:

```
for ( item=array[i=0]; i<array.length; item=array[++i] ) {
    alert(item.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of enumerating an array of objects in JavaScript:

```
for(var item in array)
    alert(array[item])
```